# What's the meaning of link#4 in mac's route table?

Tags: macos, routing

```
jichaodeiMac:~ jichaoyang$ netstat -r
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            openwrt.lan        UGSc           10        0     en0
127                localhost          UCS             1        0     lo0
localhost          localhost          UH              2       54     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.1          link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
192.168.1.1/32     link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
openwrt.lan        46:94:fc:63:fc:7   UHLWIir        11     3610     en0   1200
192.168.1.125/32   link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
jichaodeimac.lan   d0:50:99:14:b7:a3  UHLWIi          1        1     lo0
yangjicdeiphone.la link#4             UHLWIi          1        0     en0
224.0.0            link#4             UmCS            1        0     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
```

What's the meaning of `link#4` in the table?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The expression `link#x`, where `x` is some digit, is used to indicate that the corresponding address is a `link-level address`, *.i.e*, an address that operates only on the network the host is **physically** connected to.

Thus these addresses are **not** used to reach hosts outside your local network, or, in technical lingo, they are *not routable*: once packets with these addresses reach a gateway (the junction between 2 or more distinct networks), the gateway discards them. It also follows that these addresses do not need any gateway, because they are not even supposed to evade into a different network.

Link-level addresses belong to the so called [Link Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_layer), which is a mix of OSI Layer 1 (physical) and OSI Layer 2 (Data Link Layer) concepts. Several useful protocols operate at the Link Layer level, like *ARP, OSPF, PPP, MAC* (including Ethernet).

Basically, at the Link-Layer level, you need no routing because packets destined to other hosts are sent on the wire for anyone to listen to; **all** hosts on the physical connection receive the packet, those to which it is not addressed discard it, while only the true addressee keeps it to read it.

Real *routing* takes advantage of Layer 2 by *encapsulating* a packet destined to a remote host into a Layer-2 packet destined to the router, which unwraps it of the Layer-2 encapsulation, checks that it is destined to a different network, moves it to an outward-facing interface, and sends it on once again as a Layer-2 packet on the outside local network destined to the next-hop router. And so on.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I still wonder what is the meaning of x. Does `link#4` indicate a _particular_ link (i..e, network interface) different from `link#5`? If so, then is there a way to know _which_ interface `link#4` designates? For instances, is there a natural ordering to the interfaces reported by `ifconfig`, so that `link#4` is simply the fourth interface by this ordering?

Comment: @Marius when we see `169.254` in above example , does this mean `169.254.0.0` as network Id ? If yes , what will be it subnet mask as it is not specified ?

Answer (score 13):

Regarding your second question **Is there a way to know which interface link#4 designates?**, one could use the `netstat` command with the `-i` switch (state of interfaces). [Note: I prefer `netstat` not to resolve IP addresses, so in addition to the switch of interest I usually include `-n`]. So a sample (partial) output would be:

```
][ netstat -ni 
Name  Mtu   Network       Address            Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
lo0   16384 <Link#1>                       2030140     0  2030140     0     0
lo0   16384 127           127.0.0.1        2030140     -  2030140     -     -
lo0   16384 ::1/128       ::1              2030140     -  2030140     -     -
```

In this example `Link#1` is associated to the loopback interface `lo0`, that operates on the `127` network (AF_NET family--IP4) with the address `127.0.0.1` and on the `::1/128` network (AF_NET6 family--IP6) with address `::1`.

Comment: It might be more informative if you could show an example of a link mapping to an interface other than the loopback interface.

Answer (score 3):

link#4 means the ip range is on the local segment, and no routing is necessary. if the entry was not a range of ips, netstat -r shows the mac address of that single ip address. In all other cases it will show the ip (or hostname) of the router it could possibly send the packet to.